# Converting props (properties) from Java to Python3 using StanfordCoreNLPServer

Tags: java, python-3.x, stanford-nlp

I'm converting **Java** code that uses **StanfordCoreNLP** to **Python** that accesses a **StanfordCoreNLPServer**. I'm not a Java developer at all.

The java code instantiates a StanfordCoreNLP `pipeline` using the following properties.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, regexner");
    props.put("ner.model", serializedClassifier);
    props.put("pos.model", posModel);
    props.put("tokenize.language", "de");
    props.put("ssplit.isOneSentence", "true");
    props.put("ssplit.language", "de");
    props.put("lemma.language", "de");
    props.put("regexner.mapping", Init.REGEXNER);
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

I'm instantiating the Python pipeline as follows:

```
    self.nlp = StanfordCoreNLP(host, port=port, timeout=30000)
    self.props = {
        'annotators': 'tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, regexner',
        'pipelineLanguage': 'de',
        'tokenizeLanguage': 'de',
        'outputFormat': 'json', 
    }

def annotate(self, sentence):
    return json.loads(self.nlp.annotate(sentence, properties=self.props))
```

**The question is**, I'm not sure how to convert the java properties (such as `ner.model`) to Python dict keys. I presume it would be something like `nerModel` ... however, when passing the `self.props` object in - nonsense keys DO NOT ERROR. So, I don't know if the key is valid or not.

I'm not seeing documentation on the properties for Python anywhere on the Stanford page.

Comment: How are you starting up the server, with what library?  You can submit a properties file when starting the server.

Comment: I was starting it with default settings. I'm now starting it with a properties file. If you want to post this as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start the server you can use the `-serverProperties` option and submit a properties file that will customize the pipeline the server uses.

Full details here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. That page doesn't offer a lot of guidance for how to properly configure a `.properties` file. This may be because I'm not a Java developer. I'm not confident from the output that the Server is picking up a lot of these settings. I've started another more specific question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51582942/converting-in-code-java-properties-to-a-properties-file-for-stanfordcorenlpserve . Is there additional documentation that could answer this for me?